WPF curved line with PathGeometry - MouseRightButtonDown only on Stroke
I want to open an Context Menu in WPF, when clicking on my drawn line. The Problem with just using <Path.ContextMenu>... is that it opens as well when clicked inside the Fill.
Any Ideas?
Setting Fill to Transparent did not work.

"Setting Fill to Transparent did not work." - if you don't need the Fill, why is it set at all? Maybe set it to null. Otherwise use a second Path with only a transparent Stroke with a sufficient StrokeThickness, so that clicking the drawn line works smoothly.

Thanks! Did not know null != Transparent.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

There is also a line geometry. When you use that as data for a path, it has no fill. Maybe that's an option to consider.
